# Why do electrolytics have a different charge and discharge rate for the same current

Tags: capacitor, measurement, high-voltage, electrolytic-capacitor

I am measuring the charge and discharge rate of a HV electrolytic capacitor (actually three 560uF, 250V capacitors in series) to calculate the capacitance.
Note: The capacitors are hand picked for an effective combined AC capacitance of 155uF.

During charge I source 20mA and measure (digitize) from 35V to 695V.
During discharge I sink 20mA and measure (digitize) from 695V to 35V.

The curves are really flat (the charge has a very slight curve).

Computed capacitance (20 runs) using C=\$I / {dV\over dt}\$ is:

- Charge    - 166.13uF +/-0.7uF (2nd order polynomial fit)
- Discharge - 185.16uF +/-0.08uF (linear fit)

Why is the discharge capacitance consistently 11% higher?

Note: Reforming is not an issue as the test was repeated 20 times in quick succession with consistent results.

Test is performed by sourcing the current with a [Keithley 2410 SMU](http://www.tek.com/keithley-source-measure-units/keithley-smu-2400-series-sourcemeter).  Voltage is measured using a calibrated 1000:1 divider into a waveform digitizer. The voltage divider is buffered and has a 10M input impedance.

Here are the charge and discharge curves.

[image: Charge Waveform][image: Discharge Waveform]

Comment: Too confused by what you are actually measuring and how you are doing the math here to comment.

Comment: I'm going to guess it's related to [soakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_absorption), but not because I know anything specific about whatever kind of capacitor you're actually testing.

Comment: Dielectric relaxation.

Comment: It sounds almost exactly as though you are losing energy as you charge up and not getting it all back during the discharge. So I'd think of this not too dissimilar to the hysteresis curve in magnetics (where the effect is often larger.) So I'd probably look up "dielectric hysteresis" as a loss mechanism and possible explanation. This would NOT be the same idea as dielectric absorption. So do keep the two things separated and not conflated.

Comment: C is dependant on voltage for different dielectrics. which are these?  Relaxation or memory effect for the double layer electric effect means there are at least 2 distinct time constants for C and ESR

Comment: \$C=I\dfrac{dt}{dV}\$ is what you meant.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 No, I think he meant what he said. It's the same thing, just written differently.

Comment: just syntax,  I think dwell between sweeps makes the difference, std method is to apply AC CC signal over DC vias and compute C from this at various f and V bias. Usually C increases above 1Hz due to double layer effect

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 The OP hasn't said much about the hold time. But one experiment that should be done is to adjust it to see how much *leakage* impacts the result. If noticeable, change the experiment until it is not noticeable. Then check the results again. But I'm assuming the OP also "sees" the voltage present. So leakage would be obvious. (Besides, using slopes would mean starting and ending points wouldn't matter to the calcs.)

Comment: I checked my data.  Looks like time between sweeps is about 3min.

Comment: Can you tell us which caps are used by datasheet? also did you ensure each Vcap was balanced?

Comment: Capacitors are Panasonic EET-UQ2E561CA

Comment: I am only computing based on dV/dt so I do not believe residual energy storage would have an affect on the measurement (it would cause an offset rather than a slope change).

Comment: Did any voltage on each cap ever go negative or exceed 350V? Tolerance would indicate potential differences in series.

Comment: \$Ileak=3\sqrt{CV}\$(1.3µA) max. after 5 minutes; C = Capacitance in µF, V = WV  no problem

Comment: "*for the same current*" how have you verified that.

Comment: @markshancock I completely agree with you about using the derivative, which removes any offset effect. Have a look here for a measured dielectric hystersis curve: http://www.infinitefactors.org/misc/images/EESE046.png This is from experimental measurements of carbon nanotubes (two different materials are examined, which is why two sets of curves.)

Comment: results indicate you are discharging with more energy than you put in as C increased on discharge, suggesting error somewhere.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the whole setup / circuitry you used here.

Comment: Just as in Lipo series charge balancers, you will need to consider the same for caps as energy storage devices and if end-use is pulse discharge, results will change.

Comment: How do you generate the constant current source and sink? Could it be possible that the two directions have 11% difference?
 Handling the 695 V level is not an easy feat...

Comment: Did you try your experiment with just a resistor, same during charge, and discharge?

Comment: Also, what is input impedance of your voltmeter?

Comment: Added test description to the post

Comment: Thanks for adding your results and instrument.  The exponential decay of dV/dt would make me want to compute incremental C in a spreadsheet and verify I with a DMM in series. Something is missing in your results as the charge C you state is ~10% lower yet does not even reach 695V in 6 minutes suggests a larger C value than you reported. Pls verify I with DMM and report V changes between ch/disch. during idle. The exponential decay makes I look nonlinear not C. Try different sweep patterns with +20mA then short pause then brief -20mA then resume +20mA. I would expect some memory effects.

Comment: Because the charge is curved, the person that wrote the processing algorithm used a 2nd order fit to calculate R and C.  When I added the discharge calculation, I used a first order fit since it was clearly linear.  A quick eyeball linear fit of the charge waveform looks like dVdt = 640V/6s which means C = 20mA/106.6V/s = 187.5uF.
Looks like I need to look more carefully at the charge algorithm.

Comment: How does initial dt/dV change for eack ramp?  Since C = I dt/dV if C varies in direction of current, I would be surprised espcially consider law of conservation of energy implies your C value discharges more enrgy than you put in with a karger C discharge value, therefore the V or I measurement must be wrong.and most likely I, even from such a fine instrument.  Trust but verify.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I am sure the Laws of Physics are still safely intact.  If checking the Kiethley is needed, I will do that (I have some); but, there are other simpler explanations to be pursued first.  Occam's Razor.  Electrolytics (and other capacitors) can clearly still hold energy even if the output is held to zero.  If you doubt that, measure the voltage of an Electrolytics (or a CRT tube) after you have "fully discharged it".  Capacitors are not quite as simple as they are in the text books.

Comment: All bets are off if you are using different math equations for charge and discharge....

Comment: @Trevor, I would agree that using a different order fit algorithm for charge and discharge is not ideal (but not my choice); but, if a 2nd order was used for the discharge it would still result in a different result for the charge and discharge measurement.  This seems to be because of the more notable curve in the charge causing a larger 2nd order effect.

Comment: Possibly @markshancock, unfortunately, as a question on here, it is impossible to comment with any degree of certainty on your results when the math involved, with whatever errors are introduced due to measurement cycle lag etc. is indeterminate. We cant compare apples and oranges. Either way, something is off if your results are stating you are getting 10% more charge out of them than you are putting in. If you can productize that phenomenon you will be rich indeed.

Comment: Verify the current with a DMM is easy during a sweep.  CRT cap memory is the double charge layer effect , I was eluding to and why ESR changes from DC to AC (f) because the memory effect is a bigger C & ESR2 and thus longer time constant ESR2*C2 Normally to  check for these errors, a soak or dwell at CV constant Voltage for 3 minutes will have some current vs floating for 3 minutes. The memory effect is true for all secondary batteries too although LiPo has less memory but not zero.  Trust my advice. I've been a Test Engineer for decades.

Answer (score 3):

Two suggestions:

> The curves are really flat (the charge has a very slight curve).

The charge has a curve because your caps are unbalanced. One of them has lower capacitance, it charges faster than the others, then it hits breakdown voltage and begins to leak. When discharging the issue does not exist. Thus charge is curved, but discharge is not.

How to distinguish this from soakage/dielectric absorption: charge, then wait monitoring current, if dielectric absorption is not involved then current will be negligible.

Suggestion 2 is I'm wrong ;) in this case I'm interested in the real answer!

Comment: +1 Do you know what is the spice model for overvoltaged electrolytic cap? I'd like to see this scenario in simulations..

Comment: I don't know and I'm pretty sure if I asked the manufacturer for a model of a part used outside its specifications they would ask... what the wat? So, no idea. All I can tell is when I over-voltag-ed some caps smelly things happened... and on other times it worked fine. Wouldn't trust my life on it though..

Comment: Would advise the OP to check the voltage on each cap during charge compared to ratings. I mean, I rode a bicycle downhill 80 km/h. Maybe more, I didn't have time to look at the speedo due due to trees and shit blurring past at insane speed. That's a bit above ratings. Really fun to do... but I wouldn't advise it for, like, everyday use, y'know.

Comment: Working voltage for each cap is 250V and surge is 300V.  I am staying below both.  Capacitors are hand selected to have closely matched capacitances (supposedly within 2%) - I am sure they are within 10%.

Comment: Note: I added the curves.

Comment: This test does not monitor each capacitor; but, I have another that does.  Typically the voltages across the capacitors differ by <5V.

Answer (score 0):

So ultimately **The problem was with the curve**

In both cases (charge and discharge), the overall rate is very similar.
The problem is that there is a very slight curve in the case of the charge.
This is pretty much expected.  As the voltage increases, the current required to feed the leakage resistance increases thus stealing more and more current from the capacitor and thus reducing the \$ {dV\over dt}\$.  Since I am doing a 2nd order polynomial fit and using the 1st order term for the capacitance calculation, this is equivalent of using the \$ {dV\over dt}\$ at t=0 which is where it is highest.  This does make since this is where leakage has the least effect. Since C=\$I / {dV\over dt}\$, I will get a generally lower value of capacitance.

Here are the details of the curve fits

- Charge

> 2nd Order: y = -1.941x2 + 120.99x + 25.775 => C=165.3
>
> 1st Order: y = 109.07x + 37.977 => C=183.4

- Discharge

> 2nd Order: y = 0.6011x2 - 111.69x + 693.51 => C=179.1
>
> 1st Order: y = -107.97x + 689.66 => C=185.2

This explains the reason for the different calculated values; but, it does not explain why the curve does not show up on the discharge as well.

Note: On review, I realized that if I decide to do a 2nd order fit for the discharge I will need to make sure to use \$ {dV\over dt}\$ at y=0 which for the discharge is not t=0 and thus is not the 1st order term.